# Can NumberPicker in Android platform be customized to handle digitals individually?

Tags: android, android-layout, numberpicker

I'm having someone create an Android app for me, for programming a circuit board that I have. It's a pretty complicated way to program the board as an initial effort, but it is how I want to do it. But something I've requested that the person isn't sure how to approach is what I've learned by him to be called a "NumberPicker", but I want one that handle each digital individually. I want 5 whole numbers, and 2 decimal places, but I want each of the total of 7 digits to have it's own separate up and down arrow to adjust the numbers and I want each digit to also allow me to type in each of those values if I choose to type it in instead. And then the app would need to combine the entire group of individual numbers into one string/number so that final value of all numbers, combined, would be used for an input field.

I'm pretty good with Excel and VBA so I made an array and built a working example of what I'm trying do:

[image: Excel functional example]

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? I'm very ignorant to application development so though I can do it in Excel I'm not sure of the limitations of an app. Thanks so much everyone!!!

Comment: You could use a series of individual NumberPickers next to each other, but they don't let you type in the number. To do that, you'd have to just add a bunch of EditTexts and arrow buttons and handle it yourself in-code, or design your own NumberPicker-like widget that allows that.

Comment: NumberPicker can actually let you type number too. You need to use numberPicker with theme. https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/android/widget/NumberPicker